# Why don't we say Al HaNisim on Pesach?

Tags: halacha, passover, chagim-holidays

Why don't we say Al HaNisim on Pesach? Aren't the miracles performed at that time far more overwhelming (and explicit) than the miracles for which we do recite this?

Comment: Isn't there already enough extra stuff to say on Chol HaMoed? :P (The page flipping...the PAGE FLIPPING!)

Comment: There's plenty of literature about why not to say a blessing SheAsah Nisim... like we do on Chanukah and Purim. But I don't know of any about this.

Comment: Perhaps Al Hanissim was only enacted so that there would be a mention of the day in the Amidah.  The biblical holidays, which when the beth hamikdash is around have special korbanoth, are already commemorated in the Avodah (yaaleh v'yavo), so an additional prayer is unnecessary.

Comment: @Loewian I hear you.  I was thinking along those lines.  The tephilah we have for the Yom Tov defines the קדושת היום.  The Al Hanisim is not defining the קדושת היום.  It is simply expressing acknowledgement and thanks to Hashem. That is why it is placed in the מודים section.

Answer (score 3):

Elleh HaMitzvot ([#486](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31339&st=&pgnum=162)) writes that we don't say a blessing of SheAsah Nissim LaAvoteinu... on biblical Mitzvot because we would have been obligated in those Mitzvot even if the miracles hadn't happened. It so happens that the miracles did happen in order for us to be able to use the Mitzvot to remember them. He writes "שמצות התורה לא הקבעו מחמת הנסים, אדרבה הנסים נתלו במצוות the Mitzvot of the Torah were not established because of the miracles, on the contrary, the miracles were hung on the Mitzvot." This could also explain why there is no Al HaNissim prayer.

Keter Shem Tov ([vol 3 pg 142](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14390&st=&pgnum=172)) suggests that Al HaNissim was enacted by Geonim and they didn't want to add something to a Mitzva Deorayta.

Comment: Al HaNissim was enacted by Geonim?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin His footnote references himself in an earlier volume http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14392&st=&pgnum=550&hilite=

Comment: I understood him to mean that the (long modern) *text* was established by the Gaonim, not the prayer itself. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%90

Answer (score 1):

"Ya'aleh v'yavo" is an addition to the bracha of "R'tzei," which discusses our plea that HaShem desire us & our prayers enough so as to re-institute the karbanos which they represent. 
"Al hanissim" is a specific addition of thanks to the bracha "Modim" which is a general bracha of thanksgiving.

We only say Al hanissim when we have no ability to request that we reinstitute the karbanos. Purim and Chanukah have no specific karbanos for us to plea for. So Chazal found another method to mention them in Shmoneh Esrei. This shows their importance, despite not having karbanos.

As to mentioning the miracles of Yetzias Mitzrayim, we do! Chazal felt that they were so important that they require us to mention them many times in davening every single day! The daily brachos of "Emes v'yatziv" [in Shacharis] and "Emes v'emuna" [in Ma'ariv] [both, until "Ga'al Yisroel"] go into great detail about these Nissim (miracles) based on the last passuk of Shma, "I am HaShem, who took you out of Mitzrayim.

And then there are the paragraphs that were added later, such as the end of the book of Ezra-Nechemia, Kapital 9/ pesukim 5 or 6-11, (after Va'yevorech David"), which speak generally about those Nissim and then the addition of "Va'yo'sha" and "Az Yasher Moshe" which goes into great detail.

Then, on the actual Yom Tov, there is, of course, Hallel, which dedicates an entire paragraph to those Nissim (Perek 114), which we refer to on every holiday, showing the overwhelming importance of the miracles of Yetzias Mitzrayim.

Finally, in the Yomtov Amidah, we refer to these Nissim as well as our special relationship to HaShem, again, in a context of expressing our desire to bring those karbanos in the Bais haMikdash which would bring to our mind our great thanks "Al haNissim"(about the miracles) of Yetzias Mitzrayim!

Comment: "We only say Al hanissim when we have no ability to request that we reinstitute the karbanos." Why? Why not say both?

Comment: As I said at the bottom, when we bring korbanos, that is our "Al haNissim," as inherently we are "Thanking" haKadosh Baruch Hu for his kindness to us, in that He took us out of Mitzrayim.

Comment: On Pesach, we retell the story with the [Korban] Pesach, Matzah and Marror in front of us (Rabban Gamliel, quoted in the Haggadah). This "Sippur" is analogous to the Hoda'ah of "Bimei Mattisyahu" or "Bimei Mordechai." See Seder HaChinuch, Mitzvah 21, Sippur Yetzias Mitzrayim " "To relate the story ...each accd'g to his way of speaking, and to Praise His Name." See also Mitzvah 5, "The Shechita of the [Korban] Pesach." "The details...the reciting of Hallel (by the Levi'im, Minchas Chinuch) & the blowing of the trumpets (by the Kohanim, ibid) show the Hoda'ah aspect that accompanied the Korban.

Comment: With the Bikkurim (first fruits) ,which were best brought from Shavuos until Sukkos time, we thank HaShem for all the Nissim of Mitzrayim in a formal statement (Devarim, 26/4-8) before thanking-admitting to Him for coming to E.Yisroel & being blessed w wonderful crops. S. HaChinuch says, "Since a person awakens his thoughts and constructs truth in his mind w the power of speech, therefore, when HaShem, Blessed be He, bestows good to him and blessed him and his land to bear fruit, and he merited to bring them to Our G-d's House, it is fitting to arouse his heart to think "ALL is from Him, etc."

Comment: Interesting idea. Is it your own?